# kSOAP 2 Android - Send complex type to Java Axis2 Webservice

Tags: android, apache-axis, android-ksoap2

I have written an Axis 2 Java Web Service. In this webservice there is one method called "insert Entry".

From the Android i would like to parse my own object to the webservice but there is a little more that i have to know about the sending process.

**Webservice method**

```html
public int insertEntry(Object entry)
{
    return 1;
}
```

The class from the webservice is implementing serializable

**Entry object in Android**

```html
import org.ksoap2.serialization.KvmSerializable;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;

import java.util.Hashtable;

public class Entry implements KvmSerializable {

private String destination_appliance;
private String contact;
private String card;
private String tariff;
private String tara_in;
private String reference;

public Entry(String destination_appliance, String contact, String card, String tariff, String tara_in, String reference)
{
    this.destination_appliance = destination_appliance;
    this.contact = contact;
    this.card = card;
    this.tariff = tariff;
    this.tara_in = tara_in;
    this.reference = reference;
}

public String getDestinationAppliance() {
    return destination_appliance;
}

public void setDestinationAppliance(String destination_appliance) {
    this.destination_appliance = destination_appliance;
}

public String getContact() {
    return contact;
}

public void setContact(String contact) {
    this.contact = contact;
}

public String getCard() {
    return card;
}

public void setCard(String card) {
    this.card = card;
}

public String getTariff() {
    return tariff;
}

public void setTariff(String tariff) {
    this.tariff = tariff;
}

public String getTaraIn() {
    return tara_in;
}

public void setTaraIn(String tara_in) {
    this.tara_in = tara_in;
}

public String getReference() {
    return reference;
}

public void setReference(String reference) {
    this.reference = reference;
}

@Override
public Object getProperty(int pid) {
    switch (pid) {
        case 0:
            return this.destination_appliance;

        case 1:
            return this.contact;

        case 2:
            return this.card;

        case 3:
            return this.tariff;

        case 4:
            return this.tara_in;

        case 5:
            return this.reference;

        default:
            break;
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getPropertyCount() {
    return 6;
}

@Override
public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable htable, PropertyInfo info) {
    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = "destination_appliance";
            break;

        case 1:
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = "contact";
            break;
        case 2:
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = "card";
            break;

        case 3:
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = "tariff";
            break;

        case 4:
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = "tara_in";
            break;

        case 5:
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = "reference";
            break;

    }

}

@Override
public String getInnerText() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void setInnerText(String s) {

}

@Override
public void setProperty(int index, Object value) {
    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            this.destination_appliance = value.toString();
            break;
        case 1:
            this.contact = value.toString();
            break;
        case 2:
            this.card = value.toString();
            break;
        case 3:
            this.tariff = value.toString();
            break;
        case 4:
            this.tara_in = value.toString();
            break;
        case 5:
            this.reference = value.toString();
            break;
    }
}
}
```

**doBackground method of my AsyncTask**

```html
private class InsertEntryAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Integer> {

    private String resp;
    private KSoapHandler kSoap = new KSoapHandler();
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "insertEntry";
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "XXXX/" + METHOD_NAME;

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Object... params) {

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(kSoap.getNAMESPACE(), METHOD_NAME);

        PropertyInfo prop = new PropertyInfo();

        prop.setName("Entry");
        prop.setValue(params[0]);
        prop.setType(params[0].getClass());
        request.addProperty(prop);

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(kSoap.getURL());

        try {
            transport.call(kSoap.getNAMESPACE() + kSoap.getSOAP_ACTION_PREFIX() + METHOD_NAME, envelope);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer response) {
    }
}
```

**Execute call from AsyncTask**

```html
Entry entry = new Entry("Test","0","0","0","Test", "Test");

InsertEntryAsyncTask asyncTaskInsertEntry = new InsertEntryAsyncTask();

asyncTaskInsertEntry.execute(entry);
```

Please let me know how i can send the entry object to the Axis2 Webservice.

Is this the right way or are there some bugs in the code?!

Thanks for you help!

Best Regards Florens

**----- UPDATE ----**

Ok at the moment the request from Android is:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<v:Envelope xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <v:Header />
   <v:Body>
      <n0:insertEntry xmlns:n0="http://wmswebservice.development.ais.at" id="o0" c:root="1">
         <E i:type="n0:Entry">
            <destinationAppliance i:type="d:string">021</destinationAppliance>
            <contact i:type="d:string">0</contact>
            <card i:type="d:string">0</card>
            <tariff i:type="d:string">0</tariff>
            <taraIn i:type="d:string">12</taraIn>
            <reference i:type="d:string">KR</reference>
         </E>
      </n0:insertEntry>
   </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

And the default request from SoapUI is this one - This works perfect -->

```html
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wms="http://wmswebservice.development.ais.at" xmlns:xsd="http://model.wmswebservice.development.ais.at/xsd">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <wms:insertEntry>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <wms:E>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:card>?</xsd:card>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:contact>?</xsd:contact>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:destinationAppliance>?</xsd:destinationAppliance>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:reference>?</xsd:reference>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:taraIn>?</xsd:taraIn>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:tariff>?</xsd:tariff>
         </wms:E>
      </wms:insertEntry>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So how can i create a request like this with kSoap2 ? :/

Comment: very very nice code presentation. Love the way you write the code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not registered Your Entry in envelope by addMapping. Besides, Your code works just fine. With added mapping (yeah i used mock mapping asdf.com):

```
envelope.addMapping("http://asdf.com", "Entry", Entry.class);
```

it produces nice envelope:

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <v:Header />
    <v:Body>
        <n0:insertEntry id="o0" c:root="1" xmlns:n0="http://asdf.com">
            <Entry i:type="n0:Entry">
                <destination_appliance i:type="d:string">Test</destination_appliance>
                <contact i:type="d:string">0</contact>
                <card i:type="d:string">0</card>
                <tariff i:type="d:string">0</tariff>
                <tara_in i:type="d:string">Test</tara_in>
                <reference i:type="d:string">Test</reference>
            </Entry>
        </n0:insertEntry>
    </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

What is problem - i dont know if its what Your webservice needs. Install SoapUI and play a bit with calling Your WS and You will see what You need.
Add also flag transport.debug=true, before transport.call, and print to log etc. request dumps - it helps You to see what You have on out and in.

Well - Your code with added mapping should make proper call to Your WS as far as i may se "on the look".

part 2

Your declared on server side WS interface as

```
public int insertEntry(Object entry)
{
    return 1;
}
```

As i mentioned in comments, You may remove addMapping. Request will then carry not i:type="n0:Entry", but i:type="anyType" and it may be - WS consumes the request.

Else:part 3.

I have a bit knowledge about Axis WS's. Ive made only clients using Axis. But... in general - to use Entry type (i:type="no:Entry") You have to declare interface as

```
public int insertEntry(Entry entry)
{
    return 1;
}
```

where Entry will be additional class on server side. That will be something like such small POJO similiar to that in Your Android code:

```
public class Entry {
public String destination_appliance;
public String contact;
public String card;
public String tariff;
public String tara_in;
public String reference;
}
```

As far as i know Axis will build such WS. But how to do it i dont know - try uncle Google for example of fe. "Axis webservice complex function argument".

Or maybe let some Axis professional let us know here :)

part 4.

Ok, so - remove addMapping and add envelope.implicitTypes=true. If it still not ok, then (but only then) add line with setNamespace on property Entry.

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.implicitTypes=true;
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(kSoap.getNAMESPACE(), METHOD_NAME);

PropertyInfo prop = new PropertyInfo();

prop.setName("Entry");
prop.setValue(params[0]);
prop.setType(params[0].getClass());
prop.setNamespace(kSoap.getNAMESPACE());
request.addProperty(prop);
```

Comment: Hello mmprog!

Thanks for your help. I addred the mapping and now i get the following BodyIn :/

SoapFault - faultcode: 'soapenv:Server' faultstring: 'Unknow type {NAMESPACE}Entry' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@19e778da

Is that because i have this method in the webservice:

public int insertEntry(Object entry)
{
    return 1;
}

Is the parameter object false? Please help me to pass the Entry Object to the Axis2 Webservice ..

BR

Comment: I think my webservice doesnt' know the type Entry :/

Comment: I dont know well how to define Entry for Axis. You should declare such class on WS side and declare method as insertEntry(Entry entry) but i cant help You how to do it right way. You may als try to (sic!) remove the line with mapping and then it will be treated as "anyType" - it may be WS eat this as "object".

Comment: Anyways, learn how to define Entry on Axis side - You have to map somehow data to model. General types as Object are'nt very nice thing for long distance coding ;)

Comment: Ok thanks, what is then the correct way to transfer data. A String and then split the data, or what are you saying about the point with long distance coding and the object is not very nice

Comment: There is many ways. String encoding to fe. json or post like format is also something. Declaring model classes (ie. Entry on both sides) is better for complicated projects becouse You send Entry and receives Entry on WS side without playing in data parsing' things.

Comment: I suggest You to install SoapUI and play with requesting Your WS. There You see what is the format of request that is acceptable for Your WS, and later - what envelope should produce Your Android code.

Comment: Ok Ok but i don't know why my webservices says that entry is Unknow type. Where can declare or setup him this Entry type . :/

Comment: Maybe to you need the wsdl file to understand the problem more?

I found an interesting article about the axis version 1.6.2. This version has some problems and it is better to switch to version 1.5.8

Comment: I'm sorry - i have good knowledge of ksoap2, but only general about building WSs with Axis. As i read You should have interface of WS, class with implementation and treated them with java2wsdl and so on. Try to define class Entry in Your WS Java code and make new WSDL, becouse interface is changing (Object to Entry) and old WSDL will be obsolete. That is the beginning. Then use SoapUI to see if WS react properly for Your needs - test it. In soapUI You see what is input and output and if WS works ok. Then go on to make client.

Comment: Ok thanks - i posted at the end the actual requests from ksoap2 and Soap UI

Maybe you can help me know .. :)

Comment: Do you see the new request xml tags??

Comment: Ok now there is the post in the Update at the top :)

Comment: Oh my god dude -> it works ;) - WTF it was only  envelope.implicitTypes = true;

Thanks for your time ..

Answer (score 0):

You will have to [serialize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) your object using XML or JSON, to be able to send them. The concepts of a WebService is being able to communicate with applications that are written in different languages, hence the protocol does not know about Java objects.

Hope this will set you on the right path.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But there are a lot of tutorials in this way. What is the correct task to perform the right sending process?

Answer (score 0):

```
Here's the  nested  envelope
{
  
//<Body>
//<LTEcomCustTable123 xmlns="http://tempuri.org">
//<_accountList>
//<LTEComCustTableOut123 xmlns="http://schemas........">
//<CustAccount>1235</CustAccount>
//<DataOrigin>test</DataOrigin>
//</LTEComCustTableOut123>
//</_accountList>
//</LTEcomCustTable123>
//</Body>



Here's the code to get renter code hereid of n0 inside tag >>>

    val request2 = SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME)
            val al = SoapObject("", METHOD_NAME1)
            val tableOutbound = SoapObject("", METHOD_NAME2)
            tableOutbound.addAttribute("xmlns", NAMESPACE1)
            tableOutbound.addProperty("CustAccount", 13521)
            tableOutbound.addProperty("DataOrigin", "Ecom")
            al.addSoapObject(tableOutbound)
            request2.addSoapObject(al)


            val envelope = SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11)
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request2)
            envelope.dotNet = true
            envelope.implicitTypes = true
            envelope.isAddAdornments = f`enter code here`alse
            envelope.bodyOut = request2
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request2);

}
```